# Controlling height of flex children in flex-direction: row scenario

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I think that possibly what i want to do is only possible with CSS grid. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/adambundy/pen/eYmmdjK

```
<main class="parent">
    <div class="child search">search</div>
    <div class="child results">results</div>
    <div class="child map">map</div>
</main>
```

I have a basic layout with 3 children inside a flexbox parent. I've set the parent to an arbitrary 800px height, which needs to be in place (it will actually be 100% of the height of its container in application).

In the actual application of this, the .search div will be of unpredictable and variable height, so I want that to be auto height. I want the other 2 divs to expand in height to fill the remaining height. However, flexbox creates a 'track' of half the height of the container (400px) and sets all 3 items to this height no matter what. I understand that the default for align-items is stretch, but if I change that to flex-start either on the parent, or set align-self:flex-start on the .search div, the other 2 divs are still only half the height of the parent, leaving a gap below the .search div. Set align-self:flex-start on the search div to see the gap:

[image]

To see the desired result, un-comment the fixed height in the CSS on the .results item. This won't work, however, because the search div might be taller or shorter vertically. It would look like this:

[image]

*note that I know I could do this by wrapping the results and map divs in a div, and flexing in the vertical direction at the top level, then horizontally inside that new wrapper, but I'm trying to eliminate that div for more layout flexibility with the same markup.

Comment: @Paulie_D, the parent must have a fixed height - it will actually be 100% of the height of its container in the end application. I have clarified the question, and added a screencap of the gap below .search when I set that element to align-self:flex-start 

I want it to look like the last screenshot, but am unable to get it to do that without setting either results or map to a fixed height, which I wont be able to do because I dont know the height of the search div (without measuring with JS - yuck).

Comment: Ahh... I see...then, I'm afraid you are out of luck. Either try CSS-Grid or add the additional wrapper.